# How to set spacing constraint to be proportional to the height or the width?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, xcode7, xcode-storyboard

I'm trying to implement a screen which looks exactly the same on multiple devices with the same aspect ratio. I'm trying to set the right spacing of an object relative to the superview to be equal to a percentage of the superview's width.

I already know how to set it to a constant and I already know how to set proportional heights and widths but when it comes to spacing, I only know how to make it constant. I've searched a lot online but I couldn't find any solution

Thanks in advance